# An complex integral question

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

If we have
$$ f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n, $$
How do we show that
$$ \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} |f(re^{i \theta})|^2 \, d\theta = \sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n|^2 r^{2n}? $$
I can show $ \leq $ by using the triangle inequality but I don't know how to show equality. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Uniform convergence?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, can you write an answer?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $|a_n|^2$? Consider, say, $r = 1$ and $f = 2$, i.e. $a_0 = 2$ and all the other $a_i$ are $0$. Then on the LHS you will have 4, and on the RHS --- 2

Comment: If so, then it is the Parseval's identity for $\langle f, g \rangle = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_0^{2\pi} f(e^{i\theta}) \overline{g(e^{i\theta})} d\theta$ as an inner product. We only have to note that $1, z, z^2, \ldots$ form an orthonormal basis.

Comment: @Sasha Kozachinskiy yes it is $ |a_n|^2 |$, I have fixed it. Thank you for your comment, I will look into Parseval's identity.